# How to split an array at median point along an axis? (Lab color space Discretization)

Tags: python, arrays, lab-color-space

I'm following an algorithm for discretizing the Lab color space with the following steps:

1. Set channel = a.
2. Convert the image or images into their color-space representation.
3. For each bin, split into two bins along channel at the median point along the
   corresponding axis.
4. Switch channel between a and b.
5. Go back to step 3 if the number of bins is not as large as desired.
6. Calculate the representative color for each bin.

I have trouble at step 3.

What is the correct way of finding the median point of the Lab array and splitting it into bins? I've thought about calculating the median(either a or b) of the sub-arrays until they both are the same but that will not always be the case.

I try to solve the above in python.

Comment: Please add what you've tried.

Comment: I haven't tried to code a solution yet because I don't think I understand the problem completely.